# How can I make a diamond ShapeDrawable?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, drawable

I want to make a drawable shaped like a diamond that I can draw in an xml resource. I am using drawable shapes as backgrounds for textviews, how can I define this type of shape? Should I use the a RotateDrawable with a rectangle shape?